# Close database connection in MSSQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing

I am writing integration tests to verify the behaviour in my repositories. The problem I run into is that I want to start with a clean database for every test. I managed to do so by writing the SetUp as follows:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _applicationContext = new TestApplicationContext();

        _applicationContext.Database.Connection.Close();
        _applicationContext.Database.Delete();
        _applicationContext.Database.Create();

        _tenantRepository = new TenantRepository(_applicationContext);
        _userRepository = new UserRepository(_applicationContext);
    }
```

The `TestApplicationContext` sets the database name to `TestDatabase`.

This works fine until I want to check the actual database for the result of my test. Then I make a connection from MSSQL server to the same database, which won't close until I either:

- shut down MSSQL server
- delete the database with the option "close all connections"

The only way I found is via SQL commands. Maybe it's because of my n00b knowledge regarding MSSQL, but I was kinda hoping for a "close connection" button / option.

How can I close the connection to the database from MSSQL server? 
Or, is there a way I can do this programmatically from C#?

UPDATE:

Maybe I wasn't very clear. But the test SetUp fails after I opened MSSQL and viewed the contents of a table. This is because MSSQL also creates a connection to the TestDatabase, and my integration test is not able to close *that* connection. So I am looking for a solution that allows me to close the connection I created from MSSQL server.

Comment: both calling Close() on the connection, or use it inside "using" statement should do the trick I'd think.

Comment: Well, that works as long as my unit test is the only connection to the database. But when MSSQL also creates a connection, then my test setup will fail because another connection is open

Comment: Hmm, I am trying something like this now: _applicationContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete dbo.Tenants");. Would you happen to know an alternative way where I do NOT have to type the name of the database, since that will get out of sync when I start refactoring stuff. It works though.

Comment: Pitty that I still need to write SQL with entity framework. I'd rather have the possibility to yell to my dbContext that I want to get rid of the tables corresponding an entity. But, nonetheless, you solved my problem. If you'd be so kind to throw it in an answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: Thx, glad I could help, I added some extra info in the answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around the connection problem if instead of dropping and re-creating whole database you just drop and re-create selected (or all tables).

You could create little script that will do it for you in a way that you do not need to hard-code table names:
http://www.apexure.com/blog/2010/07/29/delete-all-tables-in-sql-server-database/

Alternatively, Julia Lerman in her book "Programming Entity Framework: Code First" mentiones this approach in more mature form, as incorporated as  a custom database initializer:

> As well as writing your own custom initializers, you can also find
>   initializers that other people have created. One example of this is
>   available in the EFCodeFirst.CreateTablesOnly NuGet package. This
>   initializer will allow you to drop and create the tables in an
>   existing database, rather than dropping and creating the actual
>   database itself. This is particularly useful if you are targeting a
>   hosted database where you don’t have permission to drop or create the
>   entire database.

Answer (score 2):

You're releasing the connection back to the connection pool, not actually closing it. Instead of creating/deleting the database for each test, begin new transaction in setup and rollback in cleanup. This way no changes will be committed to your database and your test will always start from a clean state.

Also, because you are testing against live database, I wouldn't call your tests "unit" tests. Unit tests do not have any external dependencies.

Comment: Ah I see. But that would mean that I will never be able to see how the actual result looks like in the database. In other words, how relations are stored, if relations are properly removed in all tables. stuff like that. How do you handle that then?

Comment: PS: good point, updated question integrations tests instead of unit tests

Answer (score 0):

The only way to reliably get an exclusive lock on a database is to use the `SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` technique. I recommend that you create a database snapshot with an empty state and restore to that snapshot each time. That will be much faster.